# Last man standing , used circular linked list

Tags: c++

**Question :** A company hiring candidates, makes them sit in a circle.
They select every second candidate and he leaves the circle (thus circle keeps getting    smaller), till only 1 is left.
So, if there are 5 people, it'll be like :-

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 4 5    (2 is selected)
1 3 5      (4 is selected)
3 5        (1 is selected)
3          (3 is left, does'nt get the job!)
```

Jhon an oversmart guy doesn't want to be a part of this spiteful company.

Where does he stand if he knows that there are 560 people in total.
**Ans :** I tried to make a program where you enter n(number of candidates)
 and it'll print the value of the one seat that will go unselected.

I Used circular linked list and deletion.

Please bear with me , as i am fairly new to coding .

**My program works for inputs 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on as ans in all these is 1.
But any other input and it's not working.**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    node* ptr;
    int data;
}start;


int main()
{
    node *start=NULL;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of students : ";
    cin>>n;

   node *temp=new node;
   temp->data=1;
   temp->ptr=NULL;
   start=temp;
   for(int x=2;x<=n;x++)
   {
       node* temp1=new node;
       temp1->data=x;
       temp->ptr=temp1;
       temp1->ptr=start;
       temp=temp1;

   }
   node* temp2=start;
   do
   {
       cout<<temp2->data<<" ";
       temp2=temp2->ptr;
   }while(temp2!=start);
   cout<<endl;


   //delete bigins here

   temp2=start;
   node* temp3=temp2->ptr;

   do
   {
        temp2->ptr=temp3->ptr;
        temp3->ptr=NULL;
        delete temp3;
        temp2=temp2->ptr;
        temp3=temp2->ptr;


   }while(temp2->ptr!=start);

    temp2=start;
   do
   {
       cout<<temp2->data<<" ";
       temp2=temp2->ptr;
   }while(temp2!=temp3);
   cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Try to reevaluate algorithm for circular linked list.

Answer (score 2):

> My program works for inputs 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on as ans in all these is 1.

This is a good observation. Actually the answer is just a small step from here.

You have `n` candidates, and you select 1 each time. If `n` is `x + 2^k` (with the biggest possible k), after `x` steps you have `2^k` candidates left and the next candidate in the line is the answer. So the answer is `2x+1`.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ^   ^   ^ |
   removed  |
       answer
```

Note: This exercise can be found in [Concrete Mathematics: Foundation for Computer Science](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025). I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies in the core loop:

```
do {
    temp2->ptr=temp3->ptr;
    temp3->ptr=NULL;
    delete temp3;
    temp2=temp2->ptr;
    temp3=temp2->ptr;
    } while (temp2->ptr!=start);
```

This loop goes through the data once only: it stops when it gets to the end of the first set of removals, because it stops the first time it gets back to `start`. That's why you always get the answer 1, which, as you point out, is correct when the list length is a power of 2.

Rather, it should loop until there is only one `node` left, which will point to itself as the next `node`. So the last line of the `do ... while` loop should be:

```
    } while (temp2->ptr != temp2)
```

Clearly the world has moved on: the first time I heard this puzzle it was about pirates drinking poison to determine who got the treasure!

Answer (score 0):

to greatly simplify your solution, implement a "soft delete".  Put a flag on your node struct called "int deleted" and initialize it to 0.  Each time you want to delete a node, just set deleted = 1.  Your pointer logic in your question is having problems and this gets rid of most of it.

When you're looking for the next one to delete, if the node has deleted == 1, then don't count it as one of the remaining ones, just keep going until you find the second node with deleted = 0, and set it to 1.

You don't even really need a circular list, or even a list at this point.  You can just use an array of ints with values of 0 or 1.  If you keep a count of how many are still around, then you can stop as soon as you get to just one remaining, otherwise you would have to traverse the whole array to make sure there are none left.

This isn't as fast, as your list never gets smaller and you're looking at a lot of deleted entries, but it's a ton simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in the second do while loop (deletion). The while statement forces the termination of loop after iterating through it once, i.e., once it reaches back the the start node, it exits. You need to change the line

```
while(temp2->ptr!=start);
```

to

```
while(temp2->ptr!=temp2);
```

Also the last do while loop seems to run into an infinite loop because of the statement just above it:

```
temp2 = start;
```

During deletion, you do not keep track of the start pointer which gets removed as soon as element 1 is deleted. Thus temp2 points to garbage then. Removing this line should fix that too.