# Last Man Standing - closed form equation

Tags: matlab

I wrote a matlab code inorder to find the last man standing for the problem given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519242/last-man-standing-used-circular-linked-list).

**Problem**: `n` people are standing in a circle with gun in their hands. 1 kills 2, 3 kills 4, 5 kills 6 and so on (circularly) till we are left with only one person. Who will be the last person alive.

```
function N = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    if mod(length(n),2) == 0
        for ii = 1:length(n)/2
            a(ii) = [ii*2];
        end
        n(a) = [];
        a = [];
    end
    if mod(length(n),2) == 1
        for jj = 1:floor(length(n)/2)
            b(jj) = [jj*2];
        end
        n(b) = [];
        n = circshift(n,[0,1]);
        b = [];        

    end
end

N = n;
```

What this code basically does is it takes a range array (1,....,n) as input and returns the last remaining index. I was wondering if there exists a closed form equation to solve this or if the above code can be simplified further.

**UPDATE**
Find the updated code below

```
function N = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    if mod(length(n),2) == 0
        n(2:2:end) = [];        
    else mod(length(n),2) == 1
        n(2:2:end) = [];
        n = circshift(n,[0,1]);
    end
end

N = n;
```

Comment: Consider direct indexing to remove entries from the `n` array.  For example `n(2:2:end) = [];` will remove things without the nested `for` loop.  Also you don't need the second `if` statement.  Just add an `else` branch.

Comment: Yes.I did... Solution looks much better now

Comment: No `end` before `else` (in updated code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Closed form solution:**

If you plot the "survivor" index *i* for *n* = 1:100 using your script, you will see a sawtooth shaped function which falls back to 1 for every *n* = 2^*k*, where *k* being integer values.
Which means that at those points *mod(n,* 2^*k)* = 0.

You can find 2^*k* to be the next minor multiple of 2 of *n*. Hence *k* is:

```
k = floor(log2(n));
```

In between the edges of the function where *n* > 2^*k* the function rises with 2 * *mod(n,* 2^*k)*. Since the function has an offset of 1 we can thus write the closed form solution as:

```
i = 2 * mod(n, 2^k) + 1;
```

or inline:

```
i = 2 * mod(n, 2.^floor(log2(n))) + 1;
```

**The plot:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This problem is also known as the Josephus problem. You can find a more general and mathematically rigorous derivation here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem.

Comment: I added a reference to the "Josephus problem".

Answer (score 3):

You can also solve this problem without loop, in a more mathematical way:

```
%for n in [1,inf[
lastManStanding = mod(n,2.^floor((log(n)/log(2))))*2+1;
```

As suggested by wolfie you can also use directly the function `log2`

```
lastManStanding = mod(n,2.^floor(log2(n)))*2+1;
```

The function mod can deal with vector, so n can be a vector.

Comment: As the question is about code shortening, it's maybe worth noting that you can shorten this (already very good) answer by using `log2`, like so: `lastManStanding = mod(n,2^floor(log2(n)))*2+1`. Do you have a source for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your updated code is broken, you have an `end` statement before your `else` statement. Your code:

```
function N = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    if mod(length(n),2) == 0
        n(2:2:end) = [];        
    end % <------------------------ PROBLEM!! end before else
    else mod(length(n),2) == 1 % <- PROBLEM!! condition not needed for else
        n(2:2:end) = [];
        n = circshift(n,[0,1]);
    end
end

N = n;
```

It can be further simplified by noting that `n(2:2:end) = [];` is common in the `if` and the `else`, so can be pulled outside...

```
function N = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    n(2:2:end) = [];  
    if mod(length(n),2) == 1
        n = circshift(n,[0,1]);
    end
end

N = n;
```

Also you can actually remove the `if` entirely because the output of your `mod` is either `0` or `1`, and that's how much you want to shift by!

```
function N = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    shft = mod(length(n),2); % Have to calculate here before n gets changed
    n(2:2:end) = [];  
    n = circshift(n,[0,shft]);
end

N = n;
```

Last optimisation suggested in the comments is to not use `N` at all. Since `n` will just be a scalar at the end anyway, use

```
function n = lastManStanding(n)

while length(n) ~= 1
    shft = mod(length(n),2); % Have to calculate here before n gets changed
    n(2:2:end) = [];  
    n = circshift(n,[0,shft]);
end
```

Note that I've not tested if the answers are *correct*, but the results are the same as yours.

Comment: One more "optimization" is to remove `N` and just let `function n = lastManStanding(n)`

Comment: It was a mistake to use additional end. Removed it now.